Fourier Transform of specific funtions
I need to find the Fourier-transform of functions $f$ and $g$ of the form:
\begin{align*}
f(x,y):=(2x+2yi+i)^{10}\exp \left(2\pi iz \left(x^2+y^2+y+\frac{1}{4}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g(x,y):=(2x+1+2yi)^{10}\exp\left(2\pi iz \left(x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}+y\right) \right)
\end{align*}
whit $z \in \mathbb{H}$. I tried calculating it "by hand" using the binomial theorem and a few identities for integrals, but the resulting expression is somewhat unwieldy. I was wondering if there is a somewhat general forumlar for the Fourier-tranform of functions of this form?
In https://abel.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M272.19/oct16.pdf the tranformation of a function of the form $P(x)\exp(-\pi  < x,x > t),$ where $P$ is a real polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $<x,x>:=\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2$  is given. I was not able to relate this form to the functions in question here.
Note: By the identity theorem it is permissable to assume that $z$ has real part $0$.
Best regards

If $\mathcal{Re}(z)=0$ we have
$$
\hat{f}(k_1,k_2)=e^{-  \frac{\pi}{2} |z|}(2 \partial_{k_1}+ 2 i\partial_{k_2} +i)^{10}   \int \exp\left(-2\pi |z|\left(x^2+\frac{ik_1}{|z|} x\right)\right) \exp\left(-2\pi |z|\left(y^2+\left(1+\frac{ik_2}{|z|}\right)y\right)\right) dx dy=
$$
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 |z|}} e^{-  \frac{\pi}{2} |z|}(2 \partial_{k_1}+ 2i \partial_{k_2} +i)^{10} \exp\left(\frac{-k_1^2}{8\pi |z|^3}\right) \exp\left(\frac{(|z|+i k_2)^2}{8 \pi |z|^3}\right)
$$
where I have used the linearity of the Fourier transform andits behaviour under multiplication for monomials. Similarly you can find $\hat{g}$. Now only remains to calculate the derivatives up to tenth order.
